# Как вывести слова встречающиеся в обоих файлах?

Tags: c++, строки, файлы

Имеются 2 файла, в каждом из них слова. Нужно вывести на экран консоли слова, которые встречаются в обоих файлах. Есть следующий код:

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
/* 2 файла, в них слова. Вывести на экран все слова, которые есть в обоих файлах */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
       SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
     char mas1[256], mas2[256];
    int  count1=0, count2=0;
    ifstream f1 ("in1.txt");
    ifstream f2 ("in2.txt");

    while (!f1.eof())
    {
        f1 >> mas1;
        count1++;
    }
    while (!f2.eof())
    {
        f2 >> mas2;
        count2++;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<count1; i++)        
        for (int j=0; j<count2; j++)            
            if (mas1[i]==mas2[j])
            cout << mas2[j];

    f2.close ();
    f1.close ();

    return 0;
}
```

Как нетрудно догадаться, он не работает. Я думаю, всё дело в том, что согласно коду выше каждый элемент каждого массива сравнивается только с элементом с ТАКИМ ЖЕ индексом из другого массива. Ну то есть первый с первым, второй со вторым и т.д. Я не могу понять, как написать программу, которая берёт, например, в первом массиве каждый отдельный элемент и сравнивает его со ВСЕМИ элементами второго массива. 
Убедительная просьба, если будете редактировать мой код, постарайтесь использовать те библиотеки и функции, что есть у меня! Ну ещё string можно, я его пойму...с остальными библиотеками я пока, к сожалению, не знакома:(

Comment: Регулярными выражениями

Comment: Не знаю, что это:( погуглила, как-то сложно там всё...не могли бы Вы попроще сказать, своими словами, что такое регулярные выражения и как я могу их использовать в своей программе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
map<string, int> m;
string s;   
while(f1 >> s)
    ++m[s];
// теперь имеем таблицу слов и количество этих слов в файле
// добавляем в таблицу из другого файла
while (f2 >> s) {
    ++m[s]; // если нет такого слова, то m[s] == 1
    if(m[s] > 1) cout << s <<endl;
    m[s] = 0;
}
```

вот и вся логика

Comment: Ого! Так просто:) не знала про существование этого контейнера...проверила, всё работает:) Спасибо большое!

Comment: Да, в жизни решаются много таких задач.  Например, чтобы различать где какие специалисты есть,  определяют для них разряд,  понятия  в  ООП  разделяют на классы, а  в этом сайте, чтобы  привлечь внимание к ответам или  отмечают как полезный или принимают ответ нажимая на галочку...

Comment: Всё, разобралась! Совсем недавно тут зарегистрировалась, ещё не всё изучила:)

Comment: если не знаете про map, то можно вместо него обойтись списком  пар строк и цифр, просто писать  придется  больше

Comment: Была такая мысль, но Вы теперь про map рассказали, и к списку возвращаться уже не хочется! :D

Comment: Ещё один вопрос...зачем в предпоследней строчке m[s]=0?

Comment: Для случая, если во втором файле таких слов больше одного, т.е. нужно, чтобы добавилось число, только если в первом файле есть такое слово...

Comment: Поняла, спасибо!